# Wrap a function as an async task

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, task-parallel-library

I have a function that I would like to wrap so that I can use the async/await pattern:

```
wcfClientService.GetSomeString(parameter);
```

It's a call from a WCF client that I'm trying to make asynchronous, but that's not important (I know WCF supports async, but let's assume we don't have access to the WCF code).

I'm trying to wrap the method with the `Task<T>.Factory.FromAsync` method, but can't seem to get it right:

```
private Task<string> WrapWcfServiceAsyncTask(uint parameter)
{
    Func<uint, string> func = i => { return wcfClientService.GetSomeString(parameter); };

    var t = Task<string>.Factory.FromAsync(
                                           // What goes here?
                                          );
    return t;
}
```

Or even better, can someone write a method that takes a method as a parameter, and wraps and returns a `Task<T>` for it?

Comment: Have you tried `Task.Factory.StartNew`?

Comment: That will block the current thread, so I'd rather use `FromAsync` that won't block any threads when you `await` it.

Comment: `Task.Factory.StartNew` just creates a new `Task` instance - it's not blocking the current thread

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What you're trying to do is [async over sync](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2012/03/24/should-i-expose-asynchronous-wrappers-for-synchronous-methods/). You have a synchronous operation and you want to pretend it's asynchronous .

You can do that with `Task.Run`:

```
var result = await Task.Run(() => wcfClientService.GetSomeString(parameter));
```

but it's pointless as you're just offloading work from one `ThreadPool` thread to another.

If you want an asynchronous operation it needs to be asynchronous to begin with in some way, either with async-await or Begin/End, etc.

If you had `BeginGetSomeString`/`EndSomeString` which is already asynchronous you could have used `FromAsync` to turn it into async-await.

Comment: Does it actually offload work from one thread to another? I thought when you `await` a task, it runs asynchronously, but in parallel on the same thread? (I need to make it async because this is directly on the UI thread btw)

Comment: That's what Task.Run does and it is appropriate when you're offloading from the the UI thread.

Comment: when you use async-await with a truly asynchronous operation then you don't need a thread, but you can't do that with a synchronous operation like `GetSomeString`.

Answer (score 3):

If you re-generate your WCF proxy with a modern version of Visual Studio, it should generate [task-returning asynchronous methods](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873175(v=vs.110).aspx) by default. Note that the WCF service does not have to change at all; it is only the client proxy that needs to be updated.

Then you can call its methods with a plain `await`; there's no need for `Task.Run`:

```
private async Task<string> WrapWcfServiceAsyncTask(uint parameter)
{
  return await wcfClientService.GetSomeStringAsync(parameter);
}
```

Comment: I'm using VS2015 and I added a service reference to my WCF service, and it did not generate task-returning asynchronous methods... do I need to use `SLSVCUTIL.EXE` for that?

Comment: I just realized I had to configure it to do that: Right-click on the service reference, and click on `Configure Service Reference...`, and then choose `Generate asynchronous methods` in the window that appears.

Comment: what happens if you can't generate the code with SLSVCUTIL? how can I make tha call async?

Comment: @GabrielEspinoza: You should be able to use Visual Studio to generate asynchronous methods.

Comment: Yes I can, but due to Enterprise restrictions, we use our own manual generated channels

Comment: @GabrielEspinoza: I don't know how to do it with manual channels.