# Async over sync performing better?

Tags: c#, asynchronous

I'm well aware that async over sync is not recommended. The reasons make sense.

When setting up a Web API controller I tested with and without async over sync. I set up a table with data from my service and a button that would update every item at the same time with individual requests to the service. To my surprise, the setup without the async over sync seemed to handle batches of five at a time; the async over sync completed updates quickly and individually: the whole lot was done in little more than the time it took for one batch.

In summary, for a Web API controller:

- async over sync appeared to run *all* the requests in parallel.
- normal code ran *up to five (5)* requests in parallel at a time.

Given the repeated Q&As and the collective literature, my conclusion to use async over sync for performance must have been flawed. **Can you explain the behavior I saw?** I suspect the answer lies in how I set my local system up, but I'd appreciate those more knowledgeable than me running the gamut.

---

"Async over sync" would be something like this:

```
public async Task SyncAsync()
{
    return new Task(() => Thread.Sleep(2000));
}
```

According to [sources](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32930167/1680677):

> It's pointless as you're just offloading work from one ThreadPool thread to another.

So I might as well write this:

```
public void Sync()
{
    Thread.Sleep(2000);
}
```

Comment: Was my question unclear? Does my answer already exist somewhere else? Or am I just drawing close and down votes because the very mention of "async over sync" is revolting to you?

Comment: What does "async over sync" mean?

Comment: Can you please put some sample code ?

Comment: @dotnetstep I'll try to put a simple MCV together. Unlike the explanation of async over sync, an MCV would cover two projects: a Web API and a Web Application consuming it, so I'm worried the Minimal part of an MCV would still be quite large.

Comment: It's highly likely something other than simply differing between "async over sync" or not is going on in the methods to explain the difference. Because, as you mention, the only difference between the two is pointlessly sending work to another thread. So an example that actually demonstrates a notable difference between the two methods is needed. (The current sample, both take exactly 2 seconds, with no appreciable different)

Comment: @ChadNedzlek The "sample" is just an explanation of async over sync as requested by Enigmativity.

Comment: [Async Programming : Introduction to Async/Await on ASP.NET](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn802603.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

**Update 1**
You are trying to say that Async execute all request in parallel but in that case it will transfer work to thread pool to thread.

1. I had explain it below as well but understand that all your request is regarding some API call or some I/O call in that case you serve more request but in case of Sync you only server 5 request as current thread is block.

In Above I have assume that thread pool have capicity of 5.

So when 6 request come it will wait in case of Sync. In case of async as all 5 request in I/O thread pool has free thread to server 6 request. This way it increase throughput of application.

Also you have to make sure that Task is not thread. Task and thread are different.

---

I go by general over here and best of what I measured during my development.

1. Async/Await is not silver bullet to improvement performance. You have to implement it correctly. Async/Await should be used when task performed is I/O based like some database call , Web Service Call or File System Call. In this case it give to benefit as I/O operation does not required thread and it unnecessary blocking one thread.
2. If you are performing CPU intensive task in async/await then it will not give you performance benefit.
3. Also you have to test your application under various load. Like if you have hosted your application IIS and locally you are testing with debug then there is always less resource consumption then you feel that Sync is good as they get free resource but when you increase the load ( Like many user at single time) then it create bottleneck in Sync as if it will not found free thread and request will not serve even though inside IIS thread is waiting for I/O completion.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh456402.aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx

Comment: I'm not sure you understood my question. I'll try to reword it. And I'll have to work on an MCV next week: I'm running out of time.

Comment: Your update indicates you now have the same understanding as me. I want to understand where that thread pool of 5 is coming from and why it differs from the thread pool it's offloading to.

Answer (score 0):

I see from your discussion with dotnetstep you are trying to put together an MVC application but I do not think I need to see that to answer your question. Dotnetstep's answer is correct but I would like to elaborate to clarify some additional questions you have made in your comments.

> I want to understand where that thread pool of 5 is coming from

That is just an arbitrary number dotnetstep chose. That number will come from processModel>maxWorkerThreads section the web.config file. This is the number of concurrently executing requests the ASP.NET can handle. This number encourages developers to minimize the execution time of requests. For example, if this number is 5 then ASP.NET can handle 5 requests concurrently. But what will happen if the request depends on some other I/O operation? What if you need to call a web service?

In a "Sync" scenario, when Request1 comes in and calls the web service, Request1's thread will wait until the response from the web service has arrrived. Same for Request2, Request3, Request4 and Request5. When Request6 comes in the server will return an HTTP 503 response ("service unavailable") since all 5 threads are waiting for the web service response. At this point your server cannot handle any more requests until one of the requests have completed and the thread has been returned back to the thread pool.

In an "Async" scenario, Request1 comes in and calls the web service, Request1's thread will NOT wait for the response from the web service but will return to the thread pool immediately. Same for Request2, Request3, Request4 and Request5. When Request6 comes in, the server has all 5 threads (assuming none of the web service calls have returned) to process the request. This is the benefit of "Async" because it does not block your thread. This way you can process more requests concurrently.

As you can clearly see this all depends on what your are doing in the request. If the request is doing work which requires pure CPU attention (CPU intensive work) then async will not help you since whether it is async or sync, the CPU is occupied and cannot do nothing else. Therefore, your request will have to wait. Pay attention to what you are doing in your Async operation. If all your doing for testing purposes is:

```
Thread.Sleep(2000);
```

then your thread is still kept occupied whether it is sync or async (there is only one way the thread can sleep, it cannot sleep and do work at the same time by returning to the thread pool).

Do something which is really async, for example, read from a large file and you will see the real benefit or async vs sync.

> and why it differs from the thread pool it's offloading to.

The thread which does I/O requests are not the same threads which are serving these ASP requests. In some cases it is not even the same machine, for example, if you call a web service which is on another machine or read from a file which is on some other machine...you get the point.

Update 1:

A little more info which can be beneficial is when you have code like this:

```
return new Task(() => Thread.Sleep(2000));
```

If the above code is being processed by Request1's thread, it will be offloaded to another thread (Request1, Request2, Request3 or Request4). And that other thread will sleep. So essentially it is costing you more because you switched contexts but you did not get anything in return. Therefore, because of context switching here, your async version will be slower than your sync version.

Furthermore, keep in mind the amount of time the client has to wait will be almost the same whether sync or async (it will not be done any faster). The only benefit is that your server can handle more requests. The work still needs to be done one way or another (sync or async).